# Prevent dictionary from coming up in Lion

Tags: macos, multi-touch, dictionary

On Lion, a three finger double tap brings up the dictionary. The problem is I have to disable this feature on multiple Macs and cannot be done by clicking on each system. How can this be achieved? Can I use a script? Is there a table with all the multi-touch commands? And maybe I could disable it there?

Comment: You can definitely use a script, but I don't know how to disable the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applescript will turn the option off. Make sure that access for assistive devices is turned on, which is found in Universal access.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "Trackpad"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            if window 1's tab group 1's checkbox 3's value is 1 then
                tell window 1's tab group 1's checkbox 3 to click
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```